# Is any real continious function locally bounded by line, passing through $f(a)$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, general-topology, derivatives

Is any real function $f$, continious at point $a$, locally bounded below or bounded above by line, passing through $f(a)$? In other words, is it true, that for any real function $f \in C_{a}\ \exists d \in ℝ$ and there is neighbourhood $U(a)$,  such that either $\forall x \in U(a)\ f(x)\le f(a) + d(x-a)$ or $\forall x \in U(a)\ f(x)\ge f(a) + d(x-a)$ ?

Comment: No. Take $a=0$, $f(x)=\sqrt {|x|} \sin (\frac1 x)$ for $x \neq 0$, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: For general functions and points where such a line exists, that is the tangent line to $f$ at the point $a$

Comment: @Tony Mathew, |x| at 0 has a lot of such lines, but doesn't have tanget.

Comment: @Tony Mathew, my guess, that your comment would be correct, if u add there "unique" - this is what i'm working at.

Comment: Even though $|x|$ doesn't have a proper tangent, each of those lines with slopes between $-1$ and $1$ are locally (and globally in this case) bounding the function from below. So even when there's multiple tangent-like lines, your desired bounding behaviour hold.

Comment: Also, for functions which are sharp but continuous at a point, there is a notion for a family of directional derivatives (I don't remember what the formal terminology is). For smooth points, this family has only member: the tangent. For sharp points, the family has multiple members.

Comment: @Tony Mathew, directional derivative - is another thing. But if u will remember formal terminology for these "tangent-like lines", it will save me tens of hours, i guess, because i can't find anything, and already working on reinventing the wheel.

Comment: @Tony Mathew, or, i would appreciate, if u give hint how to proove your's statement, that "For smooth points, this family has only member: the tangent. For sharp points, the family has multiple members."